# how to customize devise error messages with classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, twitter-bootstrap

im using twitters bootstrap alert messages. in my application.html.erb I have...

```
            <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
                <div class="alert alert-<%=key%>">
                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
                    <%= value %>
                </div>
           <% end %>
```

normally when I want to do a flash message, I would write something like

```
flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
```

however im not sure how I can give the devise error messages a key and value pair. I looked into the devise.en.yml but can't seem to associate the message with a key ie :success, :error etc.
could someone help? thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how i do it

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
<div class="message">
   <div class="alert-message <%= key %> fade in">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times</a>
    <center><strong><%= value %></strong></center>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: oh the messages display correctly, however everything appears as a yellow box. i want to be able to give it a green box, like a success version. normally i would do it by adding flash[:success] or if i wanted a red box flash[:error]

Comment: i got it. all you have to do is override the controller where the messages are normally sent.

Answer (score 37):

### For anyone coming across this that does not know how to override the devise error messages with bootstrap.

1. Create file named:

> /app/helpers/devise_helper.rb

1. Add the following code:

> ```
> module DeviseHelper
>  def devise_error_messages!
>   return '' if resource.errors.empty?
>
>    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
>    sentence = I18n.t('errors.messages.not_saved',
>    count: resource.errors.count,
>    resource: resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)
>
>    html = <<-HTML
>    <div class="alert alert-error alert-block"> <button type="button"
>     class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
>     <h4>#{sentence}</h4>
>     #{messages}
>    </div>
>    HTML
>
>    html.html_safe
>  end
> end
> ```

Comment: Very cool, thanks! This was my question that brought me here.

Comment: Please note that depending on the version of Bootstrap you're using you might have to use alert-danger instead of alert-error. So if you try Francois' suggestion verbatim and get a white background instead of pink/red, that might be the reason.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution I've found is to use a common partial for all flash messages while checking for `:notice` and `:alert` to replace with the necessary bootstrap class.

So make `/views/shared/_alerts.html.erb` like this -

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
 <div class="alert alert-<%= flash_class_name(message_type) %> alert-dismissable">
  <span><%= message %></span>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Add a helper method (I've added it to the application helper) like this -

```
def flash_class_name(name)
  case name
  when "notice" then "success"
  when "alert"  then "danger"
  else name
  end
end
```

Include `_alerts.html.erb` in the application layout (or the parent layout for your application).

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Thing is that `devise_error_messages!` by itself wraps the data into div with `class='alert'`, so the form will have 2 nested divs with the same class. Pressing the `x` button will close nested div, leaving empty div styled as `alert`. To avoid this you can omit the div inside helper return value as following:

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    return '' if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join

    html = <<-HTML
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
      #{messages}
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
end
```