# Fixing devise alert with a bootstrap alert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, alerts

Building it with rubies on Rails

When devise attempts to log in and it fails 
 it says alert type as (alert)

Am trying to change it to show Danger

[GitHub commit changes](https://github.com/GoodZillo/saasAppProject/commit/cbd1ac6b19f65935645cdb354fb500f509234c69)

I apologize in advance only been doing this for Less 3 to 4 months just looking for some help

[My attempt to use a helper class to try to fix the situation the first time](https://github.com/GoodZillo/saasAppProject/blob/master/app/helpers/application_helper.rb)

```
<% flash.each do |type, msg| %>

<% if type === 'alert' %>

<% type = 'danger' %>

<% end %>

<%= content_tag :div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{type}", role:"alert" %>

<% end %>

</div>
```

Comment: You can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234504/rails-devise-i18n-flash-messages-with-twitter-bootstrap, but if isnt what you lookin for, please explain better your question.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for.
Thanks for your help

Comment: @user8459218 if this answer solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Devise I18n Flash Messages with Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234504/rails-devise-i18n-flash-messages-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't get you wrong, you want to show a Devise alert styled as a Bootstrap alert. Try adding this piece of code to your main layout (it's usually at "app/views/layouts/application.html.erb")

```
<% if alert != nil%>
  <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
<%end%>
```